# How to display the recovered data in json tableView Customized

Tags: ios, json, swift, token

Hello i have a problem to display the recovered data of the userProfile in json on a UILable (I customized the tableview and the problem is in the header)

I had to develop the function to retrieve information (lastname, name) on the token

```
class HPMenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var tableViewModel: HPMenuViewModel?
    let kHPMenuTableViewCell = "HPMenuTableViewCell"
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, tableViewModel: HPMenuViewModel?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel
    }
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initTableViewModel()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = menuHeaderView
                let menuHeaderView = HPMenuHeaderView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: 200) )
    menuHeaderView.imageName.configuration = ConfigAvatarCircle()
    menuHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hpCommonBackground()
    menuHeaderView.loadViewModel(viewModel: tableViewModel?.headerMenuViewModel)
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: kHPMenuTableViewCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: kHPMenuTableViewCell)
}
}

func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)!) {
    // get API profile and Bearer token
    let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
    let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/profile")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    //get information in token
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
            let sub = json["sub"] as! [String: AnyObject]
            if completion != nil{
              completion(sub)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

And in this function (that I call in viewDidLoad()) I want to display the name and lastname in header

```
 func initTableViewModel() {

        self.loadMemberProfil { (sub) in

        var arrayCellModel = [HPMenuTableViewCellModel]()
        arrayCellModel.append(HPMenuTableViewCellModel(imageName: "profil",
                                                          titleString: "My Account",
                                                          typeModel: .accountCellModelTypeMyAccount))
        arrayCellModel.append(HPMenuTableViewCellModel(imageName: "request_friends",
                                                          titleString: "Request Friends",
                                                          typeModel: .accountCellModelTypeRequestFriends))

        arrayCellModel.append(HPMenuTableViewCellModel(imageName: "settings",
                                                          titleString: "Settings",
                                                          typeModel: .accountCellModelTypeSettings))

            let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "\(sub["firstname"]!)", lastName: "\(sub["lastname"]!)")      
            let tableViewModel = HPMenuViewModel(titlePage: "Menu", array: arrayCellModel, headerMenuViewModel: headerMenu)
            self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
        }

    }
```

when i run the application it displays tableview cell data(my account, settings..) but not lastname and name in header(UIView costumized in tableview)

i need help please :(

Comment: You need to show us the tableview method, add the code that you are using to display section header of tableview

Comment: I posted you can understand better ?

Comment: Unrelated but never use String Interpolation for a string. That's pointless: `firstName: sub["firstname"] as! String, lastName: sub["lastname"] as! String`

Comment: I just edited my code for a clearer version

Comment: @vadian i edit code corrected and but same problem